# Logistic regression and orthogonal array

Tags: logistic, experiment-design

I'm trying to conduct an experiment with 4 independent variables with 3 levels and a binary dependent variable.
Because I'm interested in some first-order interactions of the IVs, and an experiment with 3^4 conditions are not feasible, I want to apply an L27 orthogonal array.

I could find some documents on how to conduct an ANOVA with L27, but not with a logistic regression.

Now, I have questions.

**1. Is it sound to apply a logistic regression here to see the effect of the IVs on the DV?**

**2. Is it possible to look at interaction effects?**

**3. If 2 is okay, how can I do that?**

Any advice would be arppriciated!

You may say,
"You should discard some less important IVs."
It's an tempting advice, but I'm curious if there would be an alternative such as above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the regression design applies to the features, not to the outcome. Engineer your features as you would for an ANOVA linear regression. Then run it through a logistic regression.

This is part of the beauty of generalized linear models, that so much of linear regression translates to generalized linear models like logistic regression, just with a link function and a method of parameter estimation that differs from minimizing the sum of squares residuals.

The usual ANOVA would be $\mathbb E[y\vert X]=X\beta_{ols}$. The logistic regression is $g(\mathbb E[y\vert X])=X\beta_{logistic}$ for the same $X$ and $g(z)=\log(\frac{z}{1-z})$.